# Is it correct to say "I dodged my arm away from his punch"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage, phrase-choice, sentence-choice

Normally, we say "**a man + dodge + the thing that is moving to him**".

For example, "*he dodged the bullet*", "*he dodged the punch*".

Can we say "**a man + dodge + a part of his body + preposition + the thing that is moving to him**" or "**a man + dodge + a part of his body + adverb**"?

For example, Is it correct to say "**I dodged my arm away from his punch**" or "**I dodged my arm aside**"?

Comment: Limb avulsion is one of the few scenarios where one would dodge their arm.  I'm thinking maybe a combine accident during fall harvest.

Answer (score 1):

I would say, "He tried to punch my arm, but I dodged him."

You weren't dodging *your arm*: you were dodging *him*.

Comment: Maybe also include an answer to the question, such as *No, you cannot dodge your arm out of the way....*

Comment: Some alternatives that would work to express Tom's meaning would be "whip" or "jerk". For example, "I whipped/jerked my arm out of the way of his punch".

Answer (score 1):

Oxford Languages defines **dodge** as *avoid (someone or something) by a sudden quick movement.*

You may have found some instances of *dodge* used to mean *move a part of the body out of the way*, but this is a nonstandard usage.